# How do you get the typescript-type of a parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have interfaces and a function:

```
interface ClickEvent {
}
interface MouseClickEvent extends ClickEvent {
  property1: string
}
interface KeyClickEvent extends ClickEvent {
  property2: string
}
interface A {
  click: (event:ClickEvent)=>void
}
const a: A = {
  click: function (event) {
    console.log(event.property1)
  }
}
```

How can you check the type of the object? I'd like to know if the event is a KeyClickEvent or a MouseClickEvent. It feels wrong to simply write

```
console.log((event as MouseClickEvent).property1)
```

Because it's disabling the typing.

Comment: This reads like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) why do you want to determine the type?

Comment: I *suspect* you are looking for [Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard) but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: There is no way of checking an *interface* at runtime, since they only exist at compile time. Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that using `as` is disabling the typing -- if anything, it's using the typing.

Comment: Since TS uses Duck-Typing you can simply check if the event has property1 using `'property1' in event`. If so it is a `MouseClickEvent `

Comment: Well, my problem is that the typescript compiler does not like my code. So it's not an xy-problem. I'm using a library that defines an interface which is similar to the posted one. When following the type guard link, I get the error "Property 'name' does not exist on type '...'.ts(2339)"

Comment: You'll need to validate the property. Example: https://tsplay.dev/WJx0lN